# Labels size different from target_names: Tensorflow Multi-Input Regression converting to Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to convert a multi-input mixed input (txt, image) keras model from a regression output (house price) to a classification output (number of bedrooms).  In particular, I am altering this tutorial

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

to be a classifier.  I have a couple of technical questions about the number of categories, and I also get an error that I don't fully understand.

I have altered the last layer of the network to be a softmax:

```
x = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(x)
```

However I only have 10 categories (the dataset covers houses with 1-10 bedrooms).  But with Dense(10,...) I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 10 which is outside >the valid range of [0, 10).  Label values: 3 2 5 2 10 3 2 5

I understand the error, and how to avoid it, but why isn't the range [0,10) sufficient given that I don't have houses with 0 bedrooms?

When I try and get a classification report I get two warnings:

> UserWarning: labels size, 6, does not match size of target_names, 10
>   UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and 
>   being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.

I think these might be because my classification report only contains houses with 1-6 bedrooms.  But am not sure - any insight you can give would be appreciated.

My code and the dataset can be cloned from here:
https://github.com/davidrtfraser/blog-keras-multi-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in Machine Learning, labels for a N classes are encoded as integers in the range 0 to N - 1, because this maps directly from class indices, so you can use `argmax` to recover them from model outputs.

So you need to encode your labels in the same way, the easiest way is to substract your `[1, 10]` labels to `[0, 9]` by substracting one from each label, and to get the number of bedrooms from the model output, you add one to the output label.